# Display curentdate and last 5 days dates in java

Tags: java, date

I want to display the current date and last 5 days dates

```
2013/04/24
2013/04/23
2013/04/22
2013/04/21
2013/04/20
```

I have code as below..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date=cal.getTime();
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
                   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-1);
                   date=cal.getTime();
                   String reportDate = sdf.format(date);
                   System.out.println("reportDate :" + reportDate);
}
```

Here i am getting output like below..

```
reportDate :2013/04/23
reportDate :2013/04/22
reportDate :2013/04/21
reportDate :2013/04/20
reportDate :2013/04/19
```

but i want last five days dates including current date...can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!!

```
public static void getDate(){
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    int day = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        for(int i=day; i > (day-5); i--){
            cal.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);

            Date date = cal.getTime();
            System.out.println(sdf.format(date));   
        }

}
```

v 2.0

```
public static void getDate1(){
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    cal.set(2013, 0, 1); // this is extreme case!!!

    int day = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
    int year = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);

        for(int i=day; i > (day-5); i--){
            cal.set(year, month, i);

            Date date = cal.getTime();
            System.out.println(sdf.format(date));   
        }

}
```

This is the Output:

`2013/01/01 
2012/12/31
2012/12/30
2012/12/29
2012/12/28`

Comment: How will it act when DAY_OF_MONTH < 5?

Comment: When DAY_OF_MOUNTH < 5 the GregorianCalendar Class decrements automatically the MOUNTH and the DAY_OF_MOUNTH will start on the last day of this mounth !! tray it befor talk!

Comment: Try it with day = 2. cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2) before you start the loop.

Comment: You have fixed the error, but it's still not the best solution imho. You have to apply a workaround for something that is handled automatically by using `add` and `roll`, as suggested by @AnthonyGrist and myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your subtracting the value of `i` in each iteration. And `i` increases by `1` each iteration. You probably just want to subtract `1` regardless of `i`.

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```

**Edit**

Or maybe even a better solution

```
cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, false);
```

Comment: oh..thank u very much...if i want current and last five days dates then wt should i do here..

Comment: You can get todays date outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-i);
```

Specifically the `-i` part. In the first iteration, `i` is `0` so you don't subtract any days. In the next you subtract one day, so you get the 23rd. In the next, you subtract two days, so you get the 21st, and so on.

You want to print out the initial date, then loop four times subtracting one day each in each iteration, so:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();
String reportDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println("reportDate :" + reportDate);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    date = cal.getTime();
    reportDate = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println("reportDate :" + reportDate);
}
```

Comment: hey its not giving current date...using above code i wil get last 4 days dates only..i want current date + last 4 days dates i want...

Comment: @hemachandra It should print out the current date before the loop; it's definitely giving today and the previous four days' dates for me.